# ¿Tiene algo que ver "cogida" con "coger"?

Tags: etimología

Cuando un torero sufre una "cogida", queremos decir que el toro se le ha echado encima y le ha clavado su cuerno.
Si pensamos mal, podríamos hallar ciertos paralelismos entre esa acción y el acto sexual con penetración.

Como los españoles somos muy dados a hacer este tipo de paralelismos, me asalta la duda: ¿tiene este uso de "cogida" algo que ver con el habitual en casi toda América de "coger" para referirse al coito? ¿Hay algún tipo de influencia del uno en la aparición del otro, o viceversa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El circuito tendría que haber sido: de aquellos lugares donde se usa "coger" como "tener sexo" (y a veces más bien "forzar al sexo", porque el verbo puede ser transitivo no recíproco) tendría que haber derivado "cogida" como "acto sexual violento o forzado". Esta palabra podría haber sido asociada a la tauromaquia en su lugar de origen, es decir, en aquellos lugares de América donde se practica la tauromaquia, aunque quizá también no, porque resultaría bastante incómodo utilizar una palabra así ante una audiencia. Finalmente, esa connotación de "penetración" tendría que haber sido adoptada por personas que utilizan "coger" sin pensar jamás en la connotación sexual que tiene dicha palabra en otras partes. Creo que no es muy factible todo esto.

En dirección opuesta encuentro dificultades similares. El hecho de que "coger" y "cogida" sean palabras totalmente educadas en buena parte de España, y absolutamente obscenas en buena parte de América, hace que sea difícil la influencia en cualquier sentido.

En Argentina, así como no usamos "coger" sino "agarrar", diríamos probablemente que el toro "lo agarró" al torero (sí, con pronombre objeto redundante), si tuviéramos tauromaquia. No reemplazaríamos "cogida" por "agarrada" porque una agarrada es otra cosa (una pelea o discusión). Supongo que usaríamos el término más específico "[cornada](https://dle.rae.es/?id=AtPFIJP)".