# ¿Qué hechos históricos produjeron que "coger" tomara el significado de "tener sexo" en varios países de Sudamérica?

Tags: significado, historia

He consultado si podría realizar dicha pregunta [aquí](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4154/is-it-allowed-to-ask-why-a-certain-word-ended-up-taking-a-meaning-pretty-differe?noredirect=1#comment9691_4154) y me han redirigido a esta página para obtener una mejor respuesta.

Quería preguntar que fenómenos históricos ocasionaron que dicha palabra tomara dicho significado en dichos países. Al menos en español de España la palabra no tiene connotación sexual (al menos no hasta que se conoce que en dichos países tiene dicha connotación sexual), además es ampliamente usado y no logro ver como un verbo como "coger" puede acabar teniendo connotaciones sexuales.

A ver si aquí puedo encontrarla.

Un saludo.

Comment: Responde esto a tu pregunta?: [Coger: origen de su significado sexual en algunos países](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/33217/5481). Otras preguntas relacionadas que pueden tener respuestas o comentarios interesantes o relevantes: [¿En qué países la palabra “coger” tiene connotaciones sexuales?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8749/5481) y [¿Tiene algo que ver “cogida” con “coger”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/30541/5481). Esas preguntas explican un poco la evolución de coger o tomar con "Cubrir el macho a la hembra/ forzar el sexo".

Comment: Como punto de partida sirve. Pero lo que busco son más los hechos históricos que hicieran que en dichos países la palabra acabara siendo asociada al sexo. Busco más bien explicaciones como las que se puede ver en este blog para ciertas expresiones populares: https://eduardojmedrano.blogspot.com/

Comment: Miles de palabras tienen *significados regionales* sin que para ellos sea necesario que intervenga ningún «evento histórico»

Comment: Si se lee la pregunta en forma literal [¿Qué hechos históricos produjeron que "coger" tomara el significado de "tener sexo" en varios países de Sudamérica?] estamos hablando de "coger" *en varios países*. ¿No sería más adecuado cambiar la frase por [¿Qué hechos históricos produjeron que en varios países de Sudamérica "coger" tomara el significado de "tener sexo"?]

Answer (score 2):

En cualquier caso, no olvidemos que en el Diccionario de la lengua, una de las acepciones de coger es precisamente esta, si bien en relación con los animales:

**> 22. tr. Dicho del macho de determinadas especies: Cubrir a la hembra.**

Comment: cubrir a la hembra [risas] :)

Answer (score 1):

Pues sí, existe un hecho histórico. En la conquista de América, los españoles llegamos casi sin mujeres, los indios (los habitantes nativos) se relegaron a un estado de esclavitud o semiesclavitud a través de las encomiendas. Cuando alguien quería tener sexo, era habitual cogerse (tomar) a una india, y de ahí viene el término "coger" en el sentido de 'tener sexo'.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. ¿Podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 1):

A mí un mexicano también me contó lo expuesto. Cuando los españoles violaban a las nativas, las elegían con la frase "esa me la cojo yo" (esa la elijo yo) y acabó como verbo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo lamento, pero esa historieta que cuenta que viene de violar y "coger" a las indígenas no tiene ningún sentido... Forma de la leyenda negra y poco más

Si así fuese tendríamos que asumir que en países con tantísimo mestizaje como Colombia, donde la palabra coger no tiene connotaciones sexuales, no hubo violaciones. Tampoco la tiene en Cuba, República Dominicana, Ecuador, Panamá o Puerto Rico.

Curiosamente, en pudieses de mejor intensidad de población indígena y menos mestizaje sí tiene esa connotaciones, como en Argentina.

La palabra "coger" ha evolucionado igual que lo ha hecho la palabra "joder" que pasa de significar copular entre animales a molestar... Qué resulta ser una palabrota en España y mucho menos grosera en Argentina... No creo que exista un hecho histórico, simplemente que de la idea a la que nos remite el verbo "coger" : agarra, poseer, tomar, tocar, hacerse dueño... Surge esa acepción sexual que más tarde se populariza en algunos países sí (México, Perú, Paraguay, Uruguay, Argentina...) Y en otros no (como los ya citados). Saludos